# dash: How to capture output of trap (invoked w/o arguments)?

Tags: trap, dash

The section on `trap` in the [dash manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) states the following:

> **trap** without any arguments cause it to write a list of signals and their associated action to the standard output in a format *that is suitable as an input to the shell that achieves the same trapping results*.

Awesome! I thought I'd found an easy way to reinstate previous signal handlers that I've overridden, by feeding `trap`'s output back to the shell as a command:

```sh
trap "echo 'good'" EXIT

# save signal handlers to $traps
traps="$(trap)"

# override EXIT handler
trap "echo 'bad'" EXIT

# reinstate original handlers
eval "$traps"
```

Desired output: `good`

Actual output: `bad`

And that's completely logical because `$traps` is empty, which is in turn consistent with the manpage:

> When the shell forks off a subshell, it resets trapped (but not ignored) signals to the default action.

(The command substitution `$(trap)` forks off a subshell, so `trap` doesn't know about any signal handlers.)

---

Everything seems to behave as it should. But how do I take advantage of `trap`'s list functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redirect to a temp file:

```
file=$(mktemp) || exit
{
  rm -f -- "$file"
  trap
  traps=$(cat)
} > "$file" < "$file"
```

Note that in that regard `dash`'s `trap` is not POSIX as [POSIX does require](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap) that:

```
var=$(trap)
```

be treated as a special case where the traps are not reset in the subshell.

`zsh` and `mksh` also have the issue. In `zsh` however, you can do:

```
trap | IFS= read -rd '' traps
```